# Sorting user input dynamically without using inbuilt sorting methods in Java

Tags: java, sorting, for-loop, bubble-sort

I am trying to sort some user inputted integers separated by spaces.

**Input: 4 2 1 5 9
-- Expected output: 1 2 4 5 9**

I can't figure out how to stop the loop after the user presses enter in the loop where i < num. My code works when I enter the integers one by one. Any help would be appreciated

```
 class javasort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num, i, j, temp;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // System.out.println("Enter the number of integers to sort:");
    // num = input.nextInt();

    num = 5; // <-- the user input should be dynamic

    int array[] = new int[num];

    System.out.println("Enter integers: ");

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)

        array[i] = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        num = i; // make array as big as input ?

    for (i = 0; i < (num - 1); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < num - i - 1; j++) {
            if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Sorted list of integers:");

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        System.out.println(array[i]);
}}
```

Comment: You are missing a pair of curly braces.  The body of your first loop consists of one and only one statement.  Advice: ALWAYS use curly braces for `if` statements and loop bodies.

Comment: If that is the intended loop, then it is suspicious. If `num = i;`, then `i == num`, so `i < num` is false and the loop will end after one iteration. The line `num = i;` should be removed. `num` is 5 and you want to read 5 numbers from input.

Comment: If your intent is to change the size of the array each time you "find" a new number, then merely changing `num` is not going to accomplish that.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis the array size is supposed to be dynamic. I put in 5 because I couldnt get it to work otherwise

Comment: See my previous comment. That is not the way to change the array size. And when do you stop reading from input?

Comment: Put the question about the number of integers to sort back in and read num from input, als you commented out. But **after that**, you should not change num anymore, and also not the size of the array.

Comment: That's what Im asking. I dont know how to stop the loop so that the array can be as big as the user wants.

Comment: The answer by @ElliottFrisch looks good. It says what I said.

Comment: Yes. But if you read my question, I could already get what @ElliottFrisch did, working. I need to sort user inputted integers separated by whitespaces

Answer (score 6):

Your code was very nearly correct, and then you removed the best hint you had. Use `Scanner.nextInt()` like

```
num = input.nextInt();          // <-- get the count.
int array[] = new int[num];
System.out.println("Enter integers: ");
for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {     // <-- don't rely on indentation for flow control.
    array[i] = input.nextInt(); // <-- get a number "num" times.
}
```

Comment: I understand. But I want the input and output to be like this Input: 4 2 1 5 9 -- Expected output: 1 2 4 5 9 instead of having to press enter after every number.

Comment: The first input has to be your count of numbers. So, 5 4 2 1 5 9 should do it.

Comment: Yes I know. But im looking for a dynamic array. Where the user shouldnt have to specify what length it needs to input. This fix is not working on 5 4 or 55 77 11

Comment: Java arrays have a fixed length, you could use a `Collection`; or you'll have to copy the array to add a new element. Further, you'll need some way to indicate that input is complete. Your requirement to not use inbuilt methods is going to make this **very** difficult. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

So simple, yet so efficient:

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Comment: I cant use Arrays.sort. That is what I meant without using inbuilt libraries

Comment: guess what: Scanner, System and Integer are inbuilt libraries

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Bubble sort` algorithm. It runs o(n^2) on worst case. Didn't have to put the code here, you can do it. It will only take less than 20 lines.